# Use default transport (skip amqp) for Symfony Messenger

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq, amqp

In messenger.yaml, I route my messages to amqp accordingly

```
routing:
  # Route your messages to the transports
  'App\Message\SendNewsletterMessage': amqp
```

But in some environments, where I don't have RabbitMQ installed, I want to send the messages directly.  I don't want to simply comment out the line, because the code is deployed in multiple places.  Instead, I want to set the transport to be the internal call (as if it were commented out), but I can't figure out what the name of that default transport is.

```
routing:
  # Route your messages to the transports
  'App\Message\SendNewsletterMessage':  '%env(MESSAGE_TRANSPORT)%' # amqp or...
```

Then my environment variable can either be 'amqp' or direct.  What is the transport to use for it to make a direct call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is not possible, as direct messages is not a transport. As a workaround you can rewrite your configuration:

```
# config/packages/dev/messenger.yaml
framework:
    messenger:
        routing: []
```

```
# config/packages/prod/messenger.yaml
framework:
    messenger:
        'App\Message\SendNewsletterMessage': amqp
```

```
# config/packages/messenger.yaml
framework:
    messenger:
        transports:
            amqp: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
```

If you want to configure transport for one environments you can decorate `messenger.senders_locator`:

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    App\DirectSendersLocator:
        decorates: messenger.senders_locator
        arguments:
            - '@App\DirectSendersLocator.inner'
            - '%env(bool:DIRECT_TRANSPORT)%'
```

```php
namespace App;

use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Envelope;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Transport\Sender\SendersLocatorInterface;

class DirectSendersLocator implements SendersLocatorInterface
{
    /**
     * @var SendersLocatorInterface
     */
    private $decorated;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $direct;

    public function __construct(SendersLocatorInterface $decorated, bool $direct)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
        $this->direct = $direct;
    }

    public function getSenders(Envelope $envelope, ?bool &$handle = false): iterable
    {
        if ($this->direct) {
            $handle = true;

            return [];
        }

        $this->decorated->getSenders($envelope, $handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Drat.  Unfortunately, it's a 'prod' environment, but on two separate machines.  And I don't think .env supports arrays, if it did I could just put the messages that I wanted transported by amqp there.  It seems like a null transport should be a direct message, and act as if it weren't listed at all.

Comment: Thanks, would never have figured this out on my own.  I've upvoted the answer, not sure how to accept it though.

Comment: @TacTacelosky https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 4):

Symfony 4.3 handles this, the 'direct' transport is called sync:

```
# config/packages/messenger.yaml
framework:
    messenger:
        transports:
            async: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
        routing:
            'App\Message\SmsNotification': async
            'App\Message\OtherMessage': async


# .env
# by default, handle this sync
MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=sync://
```

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/30759